# How is algorithmic randomisation improving insertion in binary search trees?

Tags: random, graph-algorithm

I know that randomisation in quick sort input may help into avoiding the worst case scenario which is an already sorted list.  But how is this helping to improve into an insertion in a binary search tree?

Comment: It isn't. Look up the theory (complexity and bigO). In quicksort it's also not improving the worst-case, only the expected case for real-world data. But the motivation for this in quicksort does not apply to binary-trees.

Comment: You mean like a naive implementation, where in the worst case you might end up putting the smallest node at the root with everything extending in a linear fashion down one edge of the tree?